# Google Adwords API + Access multiple adwords account from my website

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I want to access multiple account of ad words from my website. Is there any possibilities to access using one client id and secret key.

Because when I change the client customer id (xxx-xxx-xxxx). I always need to change client id and secret key. And also I need to generate refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

If all your Ad Words accounts are grouped under a single MCC account, then you need not change  client id, secret key, refresh token every time. Changing client customer id is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a top level mcc adwords account - then put all the accounts under this and you will be able to access all accounts with one refresh token.